# Из microsoft sql server 2014 в sql server 5.1

Tags: c#, sql-server

Я для создания БД в приложении С# использовал  microsoft sql server 2014. Благодаря  этому на XP моё приложение не работает, с разными ошибками(пример на изображении[image: введите сюда описание изображения]).

Вопрос можно ли  microsoft sql server 2014 откатить до sql server 5.1 c сохранением структуры БД в Visual Studi 2017?

Comment: Как вы работаете с базой, через EF (У вас Code First, Database first), Dapper, что-то иное? Помогает ли выставить в свойствах базы Compability level в 90 (SQL 2005)? (Вообще, я бы порекомендовал закопать уже стюардессу.)

Comment: У вас база на клиентской машине с XP что ли?

Comment: Простите, я новичок и не совсем понимаю о чём вы но! Бд была создана мною в Visual Studi  с помощью элемента База данных , основанная  службах. Свойства Compability level вообще не наблюдаю?

Comment: Да клиентской машине будет XP или 7